# How do I delete ONLY the formatting of a range of cells... that is, leave the content in tact

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to remove the color from cells, but not the data in the cells.
I have tried these 2 methods:

```
Sheets("Output").Range("B3:ka200").Clear
Sheets("Output").Range("B3:ka200").ClearContents
```

but both delete data as well.  I Need a method which will retain the data and delete the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Sheets("Output").Range("B3:ka200").ClearFormats
```

Please note above will remove all formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A1:C4").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
```

This will remove the cell background color.